# How to inherit attributes from two (or more) independent classes in Python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm trying to use classes to write a card game with rules similar to Uno. The way I went is to create classes for each rank (from 2 to Ace) and for each suit (spades, clubs, etc.). Both ranks and suits have their attributes, such as rank itself (e.g. a "K" string for a King), value (e.g., a Jack has a higher value than a Seven), suit (a "\u2660" string for Spades), precedence (Spades come before Clubs, Clubs before Diamonds, etc.).

What I'm stuck at is, how to create cards (either classes or objects, but preferably objects) that would inherit from both ranks and suits? For example, when a player play a Six (whatever the suit), the next player is to take a card from the deck and miss his turn. So, this would imply a special method in the Six class, which should also be inherited by all four sixes in the deck.

So, my question is, am I on the right path here at all? And if yes, how can I solve the inheritance problem?

Here is what I've tried, among scores of other variants:

```
class Queen:
    def __init__(self, rank='Q', value=11):
        self.rank = rank
        self.value = value
        
class Spades:
    def __init__(self, suit='\u2660', precedence=1):
        self.suit = suit
        self.precedence = precedence
    
class QueenOfSpades(Queen,Spades):
        def __init__(self, rank, value, suit, precedence):
            Queen.__init__(self, rank, value)
            Spades.__init__(self, suit, precedence)

qos = QueenOfSpades()

TypeError: __init__() missing 4 required positional arguments: 'rank', 'value', 'suit', and 'precedence'
```

Comment: I wouldn't make a class for each type of card, a `Card` should probably be along the lines of a card itself. With that said, `__init__` in `QueenOfSpades` should only take `self` as an argument, because you know ahead of time `rank='Q'`, `suit='Spades'`, etc...

Comment: Having all the variables in your init without the defaults specified is why you’re getting a type error. You don’t need all the inputs in your `QueenOfSpades` `init` unless you’re wanting them to be modifiable by the caller of the class.

Comment: @Kraigolas, Jarvis, thank you for your comments! It seems to be working OK now. However, I ran into another problem. There seems to be something wrong with creating classes in a for loop. I tried: 
ranks = [Two, Three, Four, Five, Six, Seven, Eight, Nine, Ten, Jack, Queen, King, Ace]
suits = [Spades, Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts]

cards = []
for rank in ranks:
    for suit in suits:
        class Card(rank, suit):
            def __init__(self):
                super().__init__()
                suit.__init__(self)
        card.append(card)

deck_52 = [card() for card in cards]

Comment: What I got was a deck where all cards where Hearts! How can that be?
P.S. I found a workaround, by creating Card objects in the loop, right after each class is created. Still, what could be the problem with the initial solution?